# Fastest way to get pairs from a list ordered by their distance in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, permutation

Given a `range(n)` what would be the fastest way to get pairs from the range that are ordered by their respective distance from each in the list i.e. for two elements in a list `A` and `B` the distance is `abs(A-B)`.
This is the implementation I came up with:

```
 sorted(combinations(range(n), 2), key=lambda a: -abs(a[0]-a[1]))
```

but I would like it to be a generator and more efficient.

Comment: You could sort `combinations` directly without converting to a list first. Why do you want a generator?

Comment: Changed to not convert to a list first. I believe it would be more efficient as a generator.

Comment: Basically, both answers generate all pairs of numbers with a given distance (n, n-1, n-2, ...), rather than generating all pairs, measuring the distance and sorting: By using a better algorithm, they avoid all the subtractions _and_ the sort on the results. Any other savings are trivialities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a generator:

```
def distant_pairs(n):
    for d in range(n, 0, -1):
        for i in range(n-d):
            yield (i, i+d)
```

Or in prose: For each possible distance, from largest to smallest, find each of the pairs that is that distance apart and yield it.

Here's a small test harness to show it works:

```
for n in range(12):
    answer = list(distant_pairs(n))
    prev_answer = sorted(combinations(range(n), 2), key=lambda a: -abs(a[0]-a[1]))

    print "SIZE", n
    print answer
    print prev_answer
    assert answer == prev_answer
    print "---"
print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

An outer loop over distances would work:

```
((a, a + d) for d in range(1, n) for a in range(n - d))
```